# Save all the folder structure with DotNetZip

Tags: c#, file, directory, dotnetzip

I did this simple code with the latest version of the library DotNetZip, for some reason when I add a file I get all the folder structure. For example if I add:
C:\one folder\two folders\File.doc
Inside the zip file I will have
one folder\two folders\File.doc
But my expected result would be to have just the file.doc
This is my code, I don't know if I am doing something wrong or what..:

```
//C#
public static void MethodOne(string PathInput, int LimitKb=0, bool DeleteInput=false)
{

using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
//add file to zip
zip.AddFile(PathInput);
//save it
zip.Save(PathInput + ".zip");
}

}
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the overloaded, two-parameter call to AddFile where you specify the internal directory structure.

```
zip.AddFile(filename, String.Empty);
```

I think that would do what you want but I can't easily test it.

Comment: This is correct:  the overload lets you set a new "filepath/filename" while loading the original filepath/name...@Coda is just faster at typing than I am!